# Хранение и генерация картинок

Tags: веб-сервер, изображения, yii2, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день всем.

В php использую yii2-images модуль для работы с картинками, таким образом всегда могу получить картинку модели примерно так:
    <?php
    $model->getImage()->getUrl('400x300');
    ?>

При этом если картинки в таком формате еще нет, она будет создана и закеширована.

В других модулях везде используются фиксированные форматы, задающиеся изначально, при настройке модуля.

Вопрос 1.
Почему почти все модули используют пре настроенные форматы версий изображений?

Вопрос 2.
Есть ли аналоги yii2-images под руби он рэйлс?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не понял вопроса. Вы про какие модули?
2. Учитывая, что Йи почти калька с Рельсы, то на Рельсе есть всё, что на Йи, только лучше :)) Самые популярные аналоги: [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) и [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Рекомендую carrierwave